# Wordpress custom fields dissapear after update label

Tags: wordpress, field, advanced-custom-fields

Here is an image

http://clip2net.com/s/iMDpyT

my custom fields dissapeared. Please somebody, I need help. Why this happened

Comment: your problem is with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, not WordPress. Either way, almost impossible to tell with the information you provided, maybe try ACF's support?

Comment: Troubleshooting: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-39-master-list

Answer (score 0):

Your Condo field is underneath a tab. That means it's going to be inside the tab of Condos instead of with Commercial Distance to Town and all those other fields. Get rid of the tab and it will be grouped along with everything else. Tabs are just for organization.